# In a Java HttpsURLConnection POST, I can't read the response from the server

Tags: java, rest, post, httpsurlconnection

I'm trying to do an HTTPS POST using this sample code:
http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-automate-login-a-website-java-example/

About half way down there is a commented line of code:

```
// System.out.println(response.toString());
```

The reason it is commented out is that the response appears to be garbage, either the wrong character set or encrypted.

I need the data returned from the POST.  Any suggestions on the correct way to do that?  The code from the site is copied below.

```
package com.mkyong;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.CookieHandler;
import java.net.CookieManager;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class HttpUrlConnectionExample {

  private List<String> cookies;
  private HttpsURLConnection conn;

  private final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0";

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  String url = "https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLoginAuth";
  String gmail = "https://mail.google.com/mail/";

  HttpUrlConnectionExample http = new HttpUrlConnectionExample();

  // make sure cookies is turn on
  CookieHandler.setDefault(new CookieManager());

  // 1. Send a "GET" request, so that you can extract the form's data.
  String page = http.GetPageContent(url);
  String postParams = http.getFormParams(page, "username@gmail.com", "password");

  // 2. Construct above post's content and then send a POST request for
  // authentication
  http.sendPost(url, postParams);

  // 3. success then go to gmail.
  String result = http.GetPageContent(gmail);
  System.out.println(result);
  }

  private void sendPost(String url, String postParams) throws Exception {

  URL obj = new URL(url);
  conn = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

  // Acts like a browser
  conn.setUseCaches(false);
  conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
  conn.setRequestProperty("Host", "accounts.google.com");
  conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
  conn.setRequestProperty("Accept",
    "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
  conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
  for (String cookie : this.cookies) {
    conn.addRequestProperty("Cookie", cookie.split(";", 1)[0]);
  }
  conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");
  conn.setRequestProperty("Referer", "https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLoginAuth");
  conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(postParams.length()));

  conn.setDoOutput(true);
  conn.setDoInput(true);

  // Send post request
  DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
  wr.writeBytes(postParams);
  wr.flush();
  wr.close();

  int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
  System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
  System.out.println("Post parameters : " + postParams);
  System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

  BufferedReader in = 
             new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
  String inputLine;
  StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

  while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
    response.append(inputLine);
  }
  in.close();
  // System.out.println(response.toString());

  }

  private String GetPageContent(String url) throws Exception {

  URL obj = new URL(url);
  conn = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

  // default is GET
  conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

  conn.setUseCaches(false);

  // act like a browser
  conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
  conn.setRequestProperty("Accept",
    "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
  conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
  if (cookies != null) {
    for (String cookie : this.cookies) {
      conn.addRequestProperty("Cookie", cookie.split(";", 1)[0]);
    }
  }
  int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
  System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
  System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

  BufferedReader in = 
            new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
  String inputLine;
  StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

  while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
    response.append(inputLine);
  }
  in.close();

  // Get the response cookies
  setCookies(conn.getHeaderFields().get("Set-Cookie"));

  return response.toString();

  }

  public String getFormParams(String html, String username, String password)
    throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

  System.out.println("Extracting form's data...");

  Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

  // Google form id
  Element loginform = doc.getElementById("gaia_loginform");
  Elements inputElements = loginform.getElementsByTag("input");
  List<String> paramList = new ArrayList<String>();
  for (Element inputElement : inputElements) {
    String key = inputElement.attr("name");
    String value = inputElement.attr("value");

    if (key.equals("Email"))
      value = username;
    else if (key.equals("Passwd"))
      value = password;
    paramList.add(key + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(value, "UTF-8"));
  }

  // build parameters list
  StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
  for (String param : paramList) {
    if (result.length() == 0) {
      result.append(param);
    } else {
      result.append("&" + param);
    }
  }
  return result.toString();
  }

  public List<String> getCookies() {
  return cookies;
  }

  public void setCookies(List<String> cookies) {
  this.cookies = cookies;
  }

}
```

Comment: Can you share the "garbage" ? Maybe the response is compressed, and that's what you get.

Comment: It looks like this `▼       ?WmS?6►?~?B#?????4♦L??←Ba??ah??}bd{m??+)?\???+;♀o=?↓?H+??])??¶b?a?♥K??i:♂InL???s~;?‼Y→(?3[V@I?|???;??G$??`FW?‼??∟??7??rz2?v&↔?n??↔0?%?)???????
?w☼;???R??☺?+%u♣???ZS2?z1]y??/??#?`m]?+?L???;?▼??Z?⌂?v?+??☻??H?8‼{? n???iVjG????????m?;?-?KP←∟GR%?☻?YK?‼?‼??zO?Z????`???
?2^♠~??♠?D?[!?g?        ???&,/?K?▬&?U?$?eVc'~??}????♦??@@j6?a?M??L??↕▼??'` and goes on...

Comment: I've tried this code on gmail and one other site, and the response to the post is the same unreadable stuff.  If I do a GET with the code above, the response is the contents of the page I was getting and works fine.

Comment: Otherwise you can retrieve the HTML by other means, for instance Spring RestTemplate: https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest/

Comment: It looks like it's something specific to Google servers (maybe compression, maybe something else), [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23798402/how-to-send-post-data-to-https-server-via-httpsurlconnection?rq=1) uses the same code as yours and seems to work.

Comment: Can you give us all the details of the connection? Especially HTTP response headers. You can use Apache Commons' ToStringBuilder for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem that I was specifically having, though I didn't identify the actual issue in the code above (I was working with a different site and slightly different code).  The server was returning a compressed response (as pyb speculated above), and I solved it by changing the "Accept-Encoding" property.