# Call an https web service hosted in IIS web service from JAVA https client

Tags: java, iis-8

We have a web site in IIS, we had created a self signed certificate in IIS and in IIS https is enabled and working for that web site. There is one service in IIS which accepts post request.

Now from JAVA tomcat application I need to call this https post API in IIS server.

Please provide me clear steps need to be done on both ends and a sample code in JAVA to do a https post request with a multipart file data.

Regards,
Meerasaaheb Mohmmad

Created and exported a certificate from IIS tried to import it into JAVA certificate trust list but could not do it.

Comment: Have you tried to achieve this with httpsurlconnection? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23798402/how-to-send-post-data-to-https-server-via-httpsurlconnection. Besides, I believe there is nothing need to be done in IIS. Besides, you could create a trusted certificate for testing purpose via VS makecert https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2014/05/05/make-your-own-ssl-certificate-for-testing-and-learning/

Comment: Dear Jokies Ding thanks for your information. i will read this article and update you. Thanks for sharing the valuable information.

Comment: Looking forward to hearing from you